# Azure Storage Account nuget Package doesn't target MonoAndroid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-storage

I'm creating an Android app using Xamarin with Visual Studio. I want to install the Windows Azure Storage nuget package but it's failing to install because the System.Diagnostics.Tools package it depends on doesn't target the MonoAndroid framework. Is there a way around this? Could there be something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are adding Nuget package 'WindowsAzure.Storage.7.0.0' as older versions did not support PCL Profile 111 and thus Xamarin.

#### Package.config:

```
<package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="7.0.0" targetFramework="monoandroid51" />
```

### Microsoft Azure Storage SDK for .NET (7.0.0)

#### Target Frameworks

- Portable Class Library Profile 111: Storage Client Libraries are available to support building PCL Profile 111 applications, as well as for Xamarin application development. **This support is currently in preview.**

Comment: I was trying to install version 7.0.1 the System.Diagnostics.Tools package it depended on would fail to install. I just installed the 7.0.0 version of Windows Storage and it didn't have any dependent packages. Gonna see what happens...

Comment: @msloan11 I think the 7.0.1 prerelease is "just" broken on the dependancies, check the github issues, but 7.0.0 does work